# Mysql Hive Sync

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hive

I am working on a tool like "Hadoop Applier for mySQL" where my tool will replicate rows to an `hdfs` file which will be queried using hive.

I am able to pull the insert values from the `binlog` of mySQL and send it to `hdfs`, but it's not working as expected.

My MySQL table will has a table `(Id, Name, age)`, but in `binlog` it's coming as `(age, Id, Name)` (the fields are sorted in alphabetical order).

Is there a way to avoid this situation?

Here are my specs:

```
Server        : Centos 6.5 64bit
Mysql Version : 5.1.73 installed using yum
Hadoop        : 2.4.1
Hive          : 0.13
Python        : 2.7
```

I had ruled out Hadoop Applier since the ability to read from position has not yet been implemented, and building/installation is very hard.

Comment: No one faced this before? weird.